# Jenkins slave : Fewer environment variable in Groovy script as in Bash

Tags: bash, groovy, jenkins

I have a jenkins slave that executes a groovy script (classic not a system groovy) followed by a bash script. In both scripts I try to print environment variables:

```
script.groovy 
println System.getenv()

script.sh
printenv
```

On jenkins console log I can see the following output :

```
system.getenv():[JENKINS_HOME:/home/foo/jenkins, JAVA_HOME:/usr/lib/jvm/default-java]
[Build] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson4198172007574039094.sh
+printenv
JENKINS_HOME=/home/foo/jenkins
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
BUILD_ID=2014-09-23_14-59-28
BUILD_TAG=jenkins-project-Build-4
PARAM1=foo
```

Why in bash I can see more environment variables?

Comment: The shell is reading startup initialization files that groovy doesn't? (Things like .bashrc, .bash_profile, .profile, etc.)

Comment: No, environment variable like BUILD_ID, BUILD_TAG and PARAM1 are set by jenkins (JVM). So the sequence is that :  
if I make a System.getenv () from the JVM (jenkins) I have less variable environment than if I I run a bash script from the JVM that makes a printenv.

Comment: If the same process is running both that groovy script and the shell and those variables are supposed to be coming from the toplevel running process (jenkins) then they both should the variables. If they don't that either means jenkins is doing something "clever", different processes are running groovy and the shell or the variables are coming from somewhere other than jenkins (like shell init files).